# Binary Search Tree Traversal in Java(output not coming correct)

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, preorder, postorder

I am working on BST and right now trying tree traversal.My inorder traversal output is coming correct by pre order and post order output is not coming correct. My code is

```
public class binarytree {

static class Node{

    Node left;
    Node right;
    int value;

    public Node(int value)
        {
        this.value = value;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
        }
    }

public void creatBST()
    {
    Node root = new Node(4);
    System.out.println("Binary Search tree with root = "+ root.value);
    insert(root,1);
    insert(root,2);
    insert(root,3);
    insert(root,6);
    insert(root,5);
    insert(root,7);
    //insert(root,1);
    System.out.println("Binary Search Tree in In Order Traversal is:");
    printInOrder(root);

    System.out.println("Binary Search Tree in Pre Order Traversal is:");
    printPreOrder(root);

    System.out.println("Binary Search Tree in Post Order Traversal is:");
    printPostOrder(root);
    }

public void insert(Node node, int value)
    {
    if(value < node.value)
        {
        if(node.left != null)
            {
            insert(node.left, value);       
            }
        else
            node.left = new Node(value);
        }
    else if(value > node.value)
        {
        if(node.right != null)
            {
            insert(node.right, value);
            }
        else
            node.right = new Node(value);
        }
    }


public void printInOrder(Node node)                           //In Order Traversal
    {
    //Node node = this;
    if(node != null)
        {
        //System.out.println("Binary Search Tree in In Order Traversal is:");
        printInOrder(node.left);
        System.out.println(node.value);
        printInOrder(node.right);
        }
    }

public void printPreOrder(Node node)                      // Pre Order Traversal
{
//Node node = this;
if(node != null)
    {
    //System.out.println("Binary Search Tree in In Order Traversal is:");
    System.out.println(node.value);
    printInOrder(node.left);

    printInOrder(node.right);
    }
}

public void printPostOrder(Node node)                   // Post Order traversal
{
//Node node = this;
if(node != null)
    {
    //System.out.println("Binary Search Tree in In Order Traversal is:");

    printInOrder(node.left);

    printInOrder(node.right);
    System.out.println(node.value);
    }
}




public static void main(String args [])
    {
    binarytree obj = new binarytree();
    obj.creatBST();
    //obj.printInOrder();
    }
}
```

In preorder the output that I am getting is

> 4-1-2-3-5-6-7

while shouldn't it be

> 4-1-2-3-6-5-7

. Similarly for post order output is

> 1-2-3-5-6-7-4

while it should be

> 3-2-1-5-7-6-4

.

Don't know where I am getting wrong.

Comment: Learn to use a debugger.

Comment: i tried but I am not able to determine why it is not coming correct

Comment: got the problem area @SotiriosDelimanolis. thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Both your pre-order and post-order are only pre/post-order in the first call.
After that, you move to in-order.

Try changing your functions to recursivley call themselves instead of in-order.

Comment: These things happen at the beginning.
First time I wrote a tree it kept deleting itself and took me hours to figure out why.